# jQuery selector by xlink

Tags: jquery, css

```
$('a[xlink\\:href=#coastline]').attr('class','grey');
$('a[xlink\\:href=#onshore]').attr('class','blue-light');
```

This is what I currently have to select each item that has the xlink of `#coastline` and turn it grey and turn `#onshore` to `blue-light`

How would I be able to change the above to select any `a[xlink\\:href]` and give it a class?

I have tried `$('a[xlink:href]').attr('class', 'yellow');` but this doesn't give them a class of `yellow`

Comment: what do you mean my xlink? is it any plugin?

Comment: @jogesh_pi I edited the original post

Comment: Where do you have it? SVG or XML?

Comment: @Y.Puzyrenko SVG I'm unable to change the SVG though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xlink` can be found in xml tags and are tricky to select as they are in another namespace.

You can try to loop through all the elements and modify the DOM element className

```
var $elements = $('a[xlink\\:href]');
$elements.each(function(index, element) {
    element.className = 'my-new-class';
});
```

UPDATE: The current selector should returns null as it's an issue of namespace.
We can fix this namespace using the special selector `a[*|xlink]` [Stack Overflow post reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23034283/is-it-possible-to-use-htmls-queryselector-to-select-by-xlink-attribute-in-an)

We know that it's SVG, so to change SVG object classes, we have to use `attr` function on them.
If you just want to select all the links inside your SVG elements I'd got with something like this:

```
var $svg = $('svg');
var $elements = $('a[*|xlink]', $svg);  // Select all a xlink attributes inside svg object


$elements.each(function(index, element) {
    $(element).attr('class', 'my-new-class');  // force class attribute
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nbfdydzd/

Comment: `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a[xlink:href]`

Comment: I guess you have to escape it as you typed in your original post above with slashes.

You might want to check this post about XML/SVG namespaces and selectors
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23034283/is-it-possible-to-use-htmls-queryselector-to-select-by-xlink-attribute-in-an

Answer (score 2):

`[*|href]` will match both html `href` and svg `xlink:href`, then use `:not([href])` to exclude html `href`.

```
//document.querySelectorAll('[*|href]:not([href])');
$('[*|href]:not([href])');
```

tested in chrome

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape special characters

```
$('a[xlink\\:href]').attr('class', 'yellow');
```

Answer (score 1):

From your comment i'm thinking that you have smth like

```
 <a xlink:href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
     <text x="0" y="15" fill="red">Link text here</text>
 </a>
```

So, to change it's color you can try to change it's `fill` attribute like

```
 $('a[xlink\\:href=#coastline]').attr('fill','#ff00ff');
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jogesh_pi/vzdmpor3/)

```
$('a').each(function(i){
    if($(this).attr('href') == "#coastline") $(this).addClass('gray');
    if($(this).attr('href') == "#onshore") $(this).addClass('green');
    if($(this).attr('href') == "") $(this).addClass('yello');
});
```