# Use condition in d3.js select

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg

I want to select and remove a textPath from a SVG where `xlink:href=id`.
A textPath has an attribute xlink:href and I have a variable called 'id'.

I want to remove textPath that has xlink:href equal to the value stored in variable id.

Something like this:

```
d3.select("textPath*some condition*").remove();
```

Can this be done? If yes, how?

Answer (score 4):

You need to need to use some trickery due so `querySelector` [namespace limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23034283/is-it-possible-to-use-htmls-queryselector-to-select-by-xlink-attribute-in-an)

```
d3.select(('[*|href="#id"]')
```

Answer (score -2):

Can't you just build it with string addition? Something like:

```
var selector = "xlink:href=" + id
d3.select(selector).remove()
```

Comment: That didn't work. Gives querySelector error: DOM exception, not a valid selector